# MongoDB 4.0 aggregation addFields not saving documents after using toDate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents,

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "0"
},

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180330"
},

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180402"
},

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180323"
},
```

I tried to convert `date` to `ISODate` using `$toDate` in aggregation,

```
db.documents.aggregate( [ { "$addFields": { "received_date": { "$cond": [ {"$ne": ["$date", "0"] }, {"$toDate": "$date"}, new Date("1970-01-01") ] } } } ] )
```

the query executed fine, but when I

```
db.documents.find({})
```

to examine all the documents, nothing changed, I am wondering how to fix it. I am using `MongoDB 4.0.6` on `Linux Mint 19.1 X64`.

Comment: Aggregate command doesn't update the documents it only updates the output.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet so how to update the docs then

Comment: If you want to update all the documents then use `$out` aggregation. `db.documents.aggregate( [ { "$addFields": { "received_date": { "$cond": [ {"$ne": ["$date", "0"] }, {"$toDate": "$date"}, new Date("1970-01-01") ] } } }, { $out: "newCollectionName" } ] )
`

Comment: Using `$out` aggregation you will get the new collection with the same documents. Just rename it

Answer (score 1):

As they mentioned in the comments, aggregate doesn't update documents in the database directly (just an output of them).

If you'd like to *permanently* add a new field to documents via aggregation (aka update the documents in the database), **use the following .forEach/.updateOne method**:

---

**Your example:**

```
db.documents
    .aggregate([{"$addFields":{"received_date":{"$cond":[{"$ne":["$date","0"]}, {"$toDate": "$date"}, new Date("1970-01-01")]}}}])
    .forEach(function (x){db.documents.updateOne({_id: x._id}, {$set: {"received_date": x.received_date}})})
```

Since _id's value is an ObjectID(), there may be a slight modification you need to do to `{_id:x._id}`.  If there is, let me know and I'll update it!

---

**Another example:**

```
db.users.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5acb81b53306361018814849"), "name" : "A", "age" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5acb81b5330636101881484a"), "name" : "B", "age" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5acb81b5330636101881484b"), "name" : "C", "age" : 3 }
```

```
db.users
    .aggregate([{$addFields:{totalAge:{$sum:"$age"}}}])
    .forEach(function (x){db.users.updateOne({name: x.name}, {$set: {totalAge: x.totalAge}})})
```

---

Being able to update collections via the aggregation pipeline seems to be quite valuable because of what you have the power to do with aggregation (e.g. what you did in your question, doing calculations based on other fields within the document, etc.).  I'm newer to MongoDB so maybe updating collections via aggregation pipeline is "bad practice", but it works and it's been quite valuable for me.  I wonder why it isn't more straight-forward to do?

Note: I came up with this method after discovering [**Nazo's now-deprecated .save() method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742959/mongodb-aggregate-framework-not-keeping-what-was-added-with-addfields/69429343#69429343).  Shoutout to Nazo!

Comment: Why not updateMany instead of forEach?

Comment: @ayushnarula you probably can use updateMany instead, this was just the best answer with the extent of my knowledge.  Can you provide a code example using updateMany for this question?