# adding rank based on sorting mongodb aggregate unwind

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation

I am using [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#std-label-unwind-includeArrayIndex) to add the rank based on sorting

Here is the aggregation query

```
dbo.collection("funds").aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "amount": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "",
      "items": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$items",
      "includeArrayIndex": "items.rank"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$items"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "rank": -1
    }
  }
])
```

and this assign the `rank` field but starting from **0**, is there any way to start it from **1**

tried with set like this

```
[
        {
          '$sort': {
            'amount': -1
          }
        }, {
          '$group': {
            '_id': '',
            'items': {
              '$push': '$$ROOT'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$unwind': {
            'path': '$items',
            'includeArrayIndex': 'items.rank'
          }
        }, {
          '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': '$items'
          }
        },
        {
          '$set': {
            'rank': {
              '$add': [
                '$rank', 1
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        // {
        //   '$sort': {
        //     'rank': 1
        //   }
        // }
      ]
```

in the mongodb compass aggregation tab it shows that field got added but when i run this script using nodejs it does not add the `rank` field

even i tried with

```
 const a = await dbo.collection("funds").aggregate(
      [
        {
          '$sort': {
            'amount': 1
          }
        }, {
          '$group': {
            '_id': '',
            'items': {
              '$push': '$$ROOT'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$unwind': {
            'path': '$items',
            'includeArrayIndex': 'items.rank'
          }
        }, {
          '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': '$items'
          }
        },
        {
          '$addFields': {
            'rank': {
              '$add': [
                '$rank', 1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    ).toArray();
```

and this even prints on console as a

```
[
  { _id: new ObjectId("6220d2fe20e33d48c865b720"), amount: 1, rank: 1 },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6220d2cf20e33d48c865b71e"),
    amount: 10,
    rank: 2
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6220d2f520e33d48c865b71f"),
    amount: 12,
    rank: 3
  }
]
```

and then tried with `$setWindowFields`

```
dbo.collection("funds").aggregate( [
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { amount: -1 },
         output: {
            rank: {
               $rank: {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
] )
```

but it shows

```
err MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields'
```

Sample document is like

```
[
  {amount : 20, name :""},
  {amount : 22, name :""}
]
```

Comment: Simply `{$set: {rank: {$add: ["$rank", 1]}}}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, this is not adding the field to collection

Comment: Where did you put this stage?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit after the replace root

Comment: That's strange, because in your sample you can sort by `rank`. Should be no issue to update an existing field. Can you provide some sample input data?

Comment: Single [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#-setwindowfields--aggregation-) might be better than  `$sort + $group + $unwind + $replaceRoot`

Comment: tried that too, its not working @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit updated the question and if we can connect over linkdin https://www.linkedin.com/in/sunil-garg-bb717580/

Comment: The aggregation pipeline should work as desired: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SaHpakRjRRW

Comment: And `$setWindowFields` works also: https://mongoplayground.net/p/79oH61Rf7fi

Comment: but it is not adding to the actual document, it is working in-memory only... from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591042/mongodb-4-0-aggregation-addfields-not-saving-documents-after-using-todate it says i have to iterate over the results....  but i have 3.5m records.. is there any better solution

Comment: You did not mention that. Simply use this aggregation pipeline in `updateMany`, i.e. `db.collection("funds").updateMany({}, [<above pipeline>])`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was already answered. But you just have to add { $out: "funds" }
at the last of your code. PFB the working code ...

```
const a = await dbo.collection("funds").aggregate(
      [
        {
          '$sort': {
            'amount': 1
          }
        }, {
          '$group': {
            '_id': '',
            'items': {
              '$push': '$$ROOT'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$unwind': {
            'path': '$items',
            'includeArrayIndex': 'items.rank'
          }
        }, {
          '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': '$items'
          }
        },
        {
          '$addFields': {
            'rank': {
              '$add': [
                '$rank', 1
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $out: "funds" }
      ], {allowDiskUse:true}
    ).toArray();
```